# How to create a reverse array function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function, reverseArray(), that takes in an array as an argument and returns a new array with the elements in the reverse order (**without using the built-in method**).

Can someone help me to see what I’m doing wrong here? It returns 1 when I ran the code below.

```js
const reverseArray=array=> {
let newArray=[];
for (let i=array.length-1 ; i>=0; i--){
return newArray.push(array[i])}
};

const array = ['sense.','make', 'all', 'will', 'This'];
console.log(reverseArray(array));
```

Comment: You shouldn't be `return`ing from your function inside your loop. That's what you do when you want to give back the final result

Comment: It would probably be easier to spot the problem if you use proper indentation when writing your code. FYI, `push()` is a built-in method, so you might want to be more clear about what really is allowed. If this is an assignment, you should make sure you're allowed to use `push()`. If not, then there is no reason not to use built-ins to arbitrarily restrict yourself.

Comment: Push actually returns the `length` of the new array. That's why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the results of `Array.push()` on the first instance of the loop. According to MDN, `Array.push()` returns:

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

So it's pushing one element to the array, and returning the length of the array (1).

Instead, add all the elements to the array in the for loop, then return the array itself:

```js
const reverseArray = arr => {
  let newArr=[]
  for (let i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
     newArr.push(arr[i])
  }
  return newArr
}

const arr = ['sense.','make', 'all', 'will', 'This']
console.log(reverseArray(arr))
```